# regexp (sed) how to 1-escape special chars and 2-group them

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I need a regexp that can extract any group of two digits surrounded by the same non-alphabetic characters, like extracting "02" out of the string "my_file_name-02-and_some"

This is as far as I got :

`echo 'my_file_name-02-and_some' | sed 's/.*[-_]\([0-9][0-9]*\)[-_].*/\1/g'`

produces

`02` (phew, two hours+ for that result) but

`echo 'my_file_name-002-and_some' | sed 's/.*[-_]\([0-9][0-9]*\)[-_].*/\1/g'`

produces

`002` so it's not really working :(. Also I wouldlike it to match "my_file_name(02)and_some" and other possible surrounding character, the idea being that those two surrounding characters *must* be the same..? Gosh my head hurts.

I'm afraid that given the context, this **had** to be a sed regexp.

Comment: So in the second case what's the expected result? 00, or nothing at all?

Comment: In the second case, nothing should be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the surrounding SAME characters:

```
twonum=`echo 'my_file_name-00-andsome' | sed 's/^.*\(.\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\1.*$/\2/'`
```

will produce 00. Remember, you can use back-references in LHS too.

```
sed 's/^.*\(.\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\1.*$/\2/'
            ^this is 1st     ^that's \1 mean: THE SAME as in 1st \(...\) group
```

adding match [] and () can use this one (not nice, but hopefully working)

```
sed 's/^.*\(.\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\1.*$/\2/;s/^.*(\([0-9][0-9]\)).*$/\1/;s/^.*\[\([0-9][0-9]\)\].*$/\1/'
```

Comment: YES that's it Jomo ! This is exactly what I wanted : The surrounding characters are grouped :) The only problem that's left is that the parenthesis and bracket are ignored (because of there very nature) so `echo 'my_file_name[00]andsome' | sed 's/^.*\(.\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\1.*$/\2/'` dont match anything :( 

I think it deserves another question...

Comment: Where exactly is the part that identifies the nature of the surrounding characters ?

Answer (score 1):

This would be your issue:

```
([0-9][0-9]*)
```

If you just want two digits, then you don't need the `*`, which means '0 or more of what's before me'. That's why it's matching `002`.

Comment: Ahh ,thank you onteria_ ; and about matching special chars, and grouping them so I can be sure they are the same ?

Comment: In fact I did not realize how to properly test for a sed regexp in the bash prompt ; because bash returns the full string if a match was not found so :

`echo 'my_file_name-002-and_some' | sed 's/.*[-_]\([0-9][0-9]\)[-_].*/\1/g'` will produce

`my_file_name-002-and_some` and that means that your regexp actually works, when if you enter :

`echo 'my_file_name-02-and_some' | sed 's/.*[-_]\([0-9][0-9]\)[-_].*/\1/g'` you get a nice
`02` But it actually means your regexp failed.

That can be confusing.

Comment: @xaccrocheur I'm a bit out of time to test the full code, but the basic way I would do it would be to do this: `(.[0-9][0-9].)` which would group the character before and after the 2 digit number. Then I would use some bash to check the first and last character to see if they are the same.